# Как при наведении курсором на картинку происходила смена основного фона сайта

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

У меня к каждому блоку привязана картинка. Я хочу чтобы при наведении к привязанной картинке менялся основной фон сайта.

```
for($i=40;$i<161;$i+=40){
    echo("<div class=\"block2\" style=\"top: $i%; background-image: url(");
    if($_GET[p] > 1){echo ("$_GET[p]");}
    echo ("$i.jpg)\">\n");
    echo("</div>");
    echo("<div style=\"position: absolute; width: 70px;    height: 40px; top: ");
    echo($i-20);
    echo("%;left:295px; background-image: url(123.jpg)\">\n");
    echo("</div>");
}
```

Comment: эт не `php` а `javascrpit`

Comment: Код написан на php

Comment: и что? если хотите чтобы фон менялся при наведении курсором - это пишется не на `php` а на `javascript`

Comment: По-другому никак?

Comment: ну на `PHP` точно не получится. Скорее всего никак, только `JS`

Comment: Не подскажите как? С JS не имел дела.

Comment: Ну судя по коду вы ни с чем не имели дела.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvyvOo

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var imgBlock = $('.block');

imgBlock.on('click', function(event) {
  var img = $(event.target).css('background-image');

  $('body').css('background-image', img);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block" style="background-image:url('https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png');-moz-background-image:url('https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png')" alt="image-1"></div>
<div class="block" style="background-image:url('https://kulturologia.ru/img/avatar/avatar02467801.jpg');-moz-background-image:url('https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png')" alt="image-1"></div>
<div class="block" style="background-image:url('https://www.karry-studio.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/татуаж-1-100x100.jpg');-moz-background-image:url('https://www.schekino.net/forum/download/file.php?avatar=1758_1310800757.png')" alt="image-1"></div>
```

Comment: не работает же ваш пример....

Comment: Вы на картинки нажимали же?

Comment: ну да... ни чего не происходит

Comment: Всё отлично работает. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Максим Ленский у вас firefox?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin  да ...

Comment: @Максим Ленский поправил пример, совместимо с firefox

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/joomla/yfe72p8w/

```
<a class="test1" href="#">Ссылка 1</a><br>
<a class="test2" href="#">Ссылка 2</a><br>
<a class="test3" href="#">Ссылка 3</a><br>
<div class="test4"></div>


*{margin:0; padding:0;}
a{
  margin:10px;
}
a:hover:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  content:"";
  z-index:-5;
}
.test1:before{
  background:url('https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*x2-xkGXkay6XgIXWaYj35w.jpeg');
}
.test2:before{
  background:url('http://ru3.anyfad.com/items/t1@dd641c19-b7a2-453f-af8e-59b65d89aad3/Nevozmutimyy-lev.jpg');
}
.test3:before{
  background:url('http://www.motto.net.ua/pic/201212/800x600/motto.net.ua-46683.jpg');
}
.test4{
  height:1px;
}
```

Comment: Как это реализовать с кнопкой?  По примеру ниже

Comment: echo("<button class='new'> ");
        echo ( " <a class='test1' href=\"$i.png\",>Просмотр</a> ");
        echo ( " </button> " );